# Intellisense no retorno de função JavaScript no VSCode

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Como fazer com que o VSCode mostre o *intellisense* em retorno de chamada usando método `Map.prototype.get`?

Código:

```
function tanque(altura){
  this.altura = altura;
}

let objMap = new Map();
objMap.set('7101', new tanque(101));

let t7101 = objMap.get('7101');
let tt701 = new tanque(102)

t7101.
```

E a captura de tela (note que o *intellisense* não é de grande ajuda):

[image: Demonstração do mau intellisense]

O objeto `t7101` deveria mostrar no *intellisense* a propriedade `altura`. Como tornar isso possível?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um comentário JSDoc para isso. Veja:

```
function tanque(altura) {
  this.altura = altura;
}

/** @type {Map<string, tanque>} */
const objMap = new Map();
```

Basicamente, de acordo com a definição de tipos, `Map` é [genérico](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html). O primeiro "argumento" do genérico é o tipo das chaves do mapa e o segundo, o tipo dos valores que cada chave armazenará. Nesse caso, como você está utilizando `string` para as chaves e `tanque` para os valores, faz-se `Map<string, tanque>`.

Veja a definição de tipos do `Map` [aqui](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts#L21).

---

O JSDoc é relativamente bem suportado pelo VSCode (através do *language server* do próprio TypeScript) para fornecer certo suporte ao JavaScript. Claro que não irá impedir que você faça algo "estaticamente" incorreto em relação ao tipo. Para esse tipo de coisa, utilize o [TypeScript.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)

No entanto, é útil para ajudar com o *intellisense*. Veja no seu exemplo:

[image: Demonstração do intellisense]

Saiba mais sobre o [JSDoc no site oficial](https://jsdoc.app/). No exemplo anterior utilizei a *tag* [`@type`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html), mas existem várias outras também. E aqui está a [lista das *tags* JSDoc que o TypeScript suporta](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html) (e portanto podem ser utilizadas para ajudar no desenvolvimento de JavaScript no VSCode).

Veja que você pode ir além e utilizar a *tag* `@param` para definir o tipo do parâmetro `altura`. Pode também definir o tipo da propriedade `altura`:

```js
/**
 * @param {string} altura
 */
function tanque(altura) {
  /** @type {string} */
  this.altura = altura;
}
```

Mas se você for partir para utilizar JSDoc extensivamente, pode prejudicar a legibilidade do código. Esse tanto de comentário é feio. Nesse caso, pode ser bom considerar utilizar TypeScript, que traz diversos outros benefícios, como a segurança de uma linguagem estaticamente tipada.

Comment: Muito obrigado!